# Read file from WEB-INF folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, struts2

I am using Struts2 and IDE Eclipse. I have a `chart.xml` file, which is placed in WEB-INF folder, I am trying to read this file as:

```
String path=ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB_INF/chart.xml");
  File XMLfile = new File(path);
```

But unable to read it. I am getting the following error:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\doc\Mavenex\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\EFW11\WEB-INF\chart1.xm (The system cannot find the file specified)]
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You can put the file in F:\doc\Mavenex\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\EFW11\WEB-INF\ this directory.

Comment: thanks for reply, I need to find the exact location of WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WEB-INF is private directory of project structure and only accessible by web server. you can not read file from WEB-INF directory. Put your file in other folder and try to read it.

Comment: Lalit thanks for reply,I put my file in WebContet  still getting same error

Comment: You must try 'File xmlfile = new File(ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/filename.xml"));'

Comment: I create a properties file and put the file path in properties file and read that file path from properties file

Answer (score 1):

[ServletContext.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) has two APIs that you can use to manipulate resources. Instead of using `File` Class to get the file, use those APIs, they are very useful for what you want to do. They are `getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String path)` which returns a `java.io.InputStream and`getResource(java.lang.String path)`which returns a`java.net.URL`.